# Mono: Error while loading one of my project files

Tags: mono, project

Everything else loads correctly except for this one project file and I get this error

> Error while trying to load
>   '/Volumes/FlashDrive/MacFolder/Alain.P1.MacOS/P1.MacOS.csproj':
>   Unknown solution item.

Anyone know a fix for this? Thanks.

Comment: You might want to add some more information: if I'm reading this right, there are a number of things that could be causing this issue.

When I've seen this issue in the past, I had to install an extension in the MonoDevelop IDE so that it could recognize a particular file type.